# How to overrite an excel document when saving it throgh excel automation object without prompt dialog?

Tags: c++, excel, com, activex

I create an excel com-object, set data and save it in a file.

This code does it:

```
Excel::_ApplicationPtr pApplication( L"Excel.Application" );

Excel::_WorksheetPtr pSheet = pApplication->ActiveSheet;

pSheet->Name = L"Test_Sheet";

Excel::RangePtr pRangeHead = pSheet->Range[ L"A1" ];

pRangeHead->Value2 = L"MyTextData";

Excel::_WorkbookPtr pBook = pApplication->Workbooks->Add( (long)Excel::xlWorksheet );

pBook->SaveAs(L"D:\\TestExcelFile", vtMissing,vtMissing,vtMissing,vtMissing,vtMissing, Excel::xlShared );
```

The problem is that when saving and the file "D:\TestExcelFile" already exists, a dialog appears asking if I want to replace the existing file.

Is it possible to make it overwrite the existing file without asking for the user's permission?

Comment: I'm not in VBA right now, but if memory serves me correct (which is why I'm posting this as a comment rather than a solution), try putting in `application.displayalerts = False` above the save line and `application.displayalerts = True` after.

Comment: thank you, John Bustos, than gave a direction to search in. this solved the problem:
        'm_pApplication->PutDisplayAlerts( LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, VARIANT_FALSE );
        m_pBook->SaveAs( ... );
        m_pApplication->PutDisplayAlerts( LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, VARIANT_TRUE );'